# Android: Resize GIF to cover screen width

Tags: android

I've been searching for a while now to solve this problem. I created my own GIF view. I want to resize this GIF view such that it will cover the screen width, dependent on the screen size of the actual device. I got it working so that the GIF will show in it's actual size, but for the device of my friend, it is portrayed too small. I'm using the `Movie` class provided by Android.

I tried adjusting the canvas but that didn't work. I also tried multiple things with the onMeasure method but they also didn't work. The closest I got was that the GIF was larger but the window in which it appeared was still the same size as before. The code of the GIF view is down below, alongside with the xml file where it is used.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/spacevert"
tools:context="com.wina.hengst.hengstdrinkinggame.Multiplayer" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
    android:text="@string/be_ready"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_below="@id/timerTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.wina.hengst.hengstdrinkinggame.GIF
        android:id="@+id/gif"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/linear"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:gravity="center"  />





<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sliderMulti"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/hiddenMulti"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/sliderMulti"
    android:text="@string/hidden"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:checked="true" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/sliderMulti"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/startMulti"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/progress"
    android:background="@color/Hengstgroen"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
```

```
package com.wina.hengst.hengstdrinkinggame;

import java.io.InputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GIF extends View {

private InputStream gifInputStream;
private Movie gifMovie;
private int movieWidth, movieHeight;
private long movieDuration;
private long mMovieStart;

public GIF(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public GIF(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public GIF(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, 
        int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context){
    setFocusable(true);

    gifInputStream = context.getResources()
            .openRawResource(R.drawable.sweetlemonade);

    gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
    movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
    movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
    movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, 
        int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(movieWidth, movieHeight);
}

public int getMovieWidth(){
    return movieWidth;
}

public int getMovieHeight(){
    return movieHeight;
}

public long getMovieDuration(){
    return movieDuration;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
        mMovieStart = now;
    }


    if (gifMovie != null) {

        int dur = gifMovie.duration();
        if (dur == 0) {
            dur = 1000;
        }

        int relTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % dur);

        gifMovie.setTime(relTime);
        gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
        invalidate();

    }

}

public void restart() {
    mMovieStart = 0;
}


}
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT** 
I found it was too hard to try and solve this problem. I've just converted the gif into multiple images and used an animation xml provided by android. This is something I can resize easily by adjusting the xml with the `ImageView`. For the conversion I used GIMP and a plugin called export layers. If any of you know the answer, you can always write the answer here and I'll try it.

Comment: try setting android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" in XML for your gif view

Comment: I tried it, but then the whole GIF disappeared. I also tried it with the ImageView combined, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Glide library, it can put GIFs in ImageViews. You also need to set `layout_width` in your ImageView to `match_parent`.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide